# Creating Excel sheet using python, prog is not working

Tags: python

```
for key, value in fetched.keys():
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Here is the program

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
import xlsxwriter
import pprint
from csv import DictWriter

xmlDoc = open('C:/Users/Talha/Documents/abc.xml', 'r')
xmlDocData = xmlDoc.read()
xmlDocTree = etree.XML(xmlDocData)
sections = ['Srno','State','Statecd','District','IssuedOn','Day','normal_rainfall','normal_temp_max','normal_temp_min']
fetched = dict()
for sec in sections:
    fetched[sec] = []
    for item in xmlDocTree.iter( sec ):
        fetched[sec].append( item.text )
#print fetched['State']

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('data.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
row = 0
col = 0

for key, value in fetched.keys():
    worksheet.write(row, col, key)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, value)
    row += 1

workbook.close()
```

fetched dict contain data like this

```
 fetched = {'Srno': ['1','2','3'....], 'State':['dads','dadada'.....],'District':['dadad','gdgdfg'......]}
```

Comment: use `for key in fetched.keys():` or rather `for key, value in fetched.items():` in your case

Answer (score 0):

Use .items() while traversing the dictionary with key and value at the same time.

Use

```
for key, value in fetched.items():
    worksheet.write(row, col, key)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, ','.join(value))
    row += 1
```

Change keys to items.

You are trying to write a list to a cell. Convert the list to a string.
Use the following concept.

```
l = ['1','2','3']
print ','.join(l)
```

Convert the list to a string using a join with a separator.

Comment: I tried this too but got error like this                                                                   
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 65, in cell_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 433, in write
    raise TypeError("Unsupported type %s in write()" % type(token))
TypeError: Unsupported type <type 'list'> in write()                                                          @big bounty

Comment: but fetched is not a list its a dict @bigbounty

Comment: But the value inside the fetched for key,'Srno' is a list

Comment: ya its works but the data are list in horizotal way and also not in there respective cells

Comment: That's because I have used a comma as a separator. If you have enabled comma as a separator in your excel settings then, the format won't be same. Instead try a different separator like ';' or '|'